# Suppose the a surface S parametrised by $\sigma$ has a first fundamental form $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ everywhere.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Prove that $\sigma_{uu} =$ L **N**,  $\sigma_{uv} =$ M **N** and $\sigma_{vv} =$ N **N**.

Show that $LN- M^2 \equiv 0$ ,using that $(\sigma_{uu})_v = (\sigma_{uv})_u$,  without using the Theorema Egregium.

I managed to porve the first part using the fundamental equations for surface theory, and in there solving for the Christoffel Symbols, which all of them came up to be zero and proving the first part.

While trying to prove the second part, I encounter that I am not able to do by conmuting derivates or substituing with the solutions proved in the first part.

Also, I have stated that this matter has to be solved without using the Theorema Egregium because there is one last exercise that indicates to use that mentioned Theorema in order to arrive to the same conclussion of what I am trying to prove.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Okay, sorry I have just clarify ti a little bit and put you in more context of the exercise I am trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual exercise. Most people would use the Gauss equations, which are derived by considering the mixed third-order partial derivatives. I will give you the outline, without doing every detail.

Differentiate $\sigma_{uu} = L\mathbf N$ with respect to $v$ and $\sigma_{uv} = M\mathbf N$ with respect to $u$ and set them equal. By manipulating, arrive at
$$M\mathbf N_u - L\mathbf N_v = (L_v-M_u)\mathbf N.$$
Similarly, using $\sigma_{uvv}$ and $\sigma_{vvu}$, you should arrive at
$$N\mathbf N_u - M\mathbf N_v = (M_v-N_u)\mathbf N.$$
Lastly, take the cross product of the two displayed equations.

Now would one think to do this? Remember that $LN-M^2$ is the determinant of the second fundamental form and Gaussian curvature is the determinant of the Weingarten map or shape operator. The latter is the derivative of the Gauss map, $\mathbf N$. So the determinant of the derivative of $\mathbf N$ should be related to the magnitude of the cross product of $\mathbf N_u$ and $\mathbf N_v$.